# Change default Ubuntu pip to pip2.7

Tags: python, pip

As the title says, is there a way to change the default pip to pip2.7

When I run `sudo which pip`, I get `/usr/local/bin/pip`

When I run `sudo pip -V`, I get `pip 1.5.6 from /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (python 3.4)`

If there is no problem at all with this mixed version, please do tell. If there is a problem with downloading dependencies from different pip versions, how can I change to pip2.7?

I know I can `pip2.7 install somePackage` but I don't like it. I feel I could forget to do this at any point.

Other info: Ubuntu 15.10

Answer (score 11):

**Concise Answer**

1.  Locate pip:

```
$ which pip
/usr/local/bin/pip
```

2.  List all pips in location learned above:

```
$ ls /usr/local/bin/pip*
/usr/local/bin/pip   /usr/local/bin/pip2.7  /usr/local/bin/pip3.5
/usr/local/bin/pip2  /usr/local/bin/pip3
```

3.  Select which one should be your default, i.e. `/usr/local/bin/pip2.7`, and copy it into `pip`:

```
$ sudo cp /usr/local/bin/pip2.7 /usr/local/bin/pip
```

---

Verify:

```
$ pip -V
pip 10.0.1 from /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip (python 2.7)
```

Comment: In step #3 I suggset making a symlink (`sudo rm /usr/local/bin/pip; sudo ln -s /usr/local/bin/pip2.7 /usr/local/bin/pip`) instead of the `cp` because 1) there's no need to duplicate the data and moreover 2) with the `cp` approach the pip in your path will not reflect any changes to /usr/local/bin/pip2.7 e.g. trying to remove it.

Answer (score 5):

- You can use `alias pip = 'pip2.7'`Put this in your `.bashrc` file(If you're using bash,if zsh it should be `.zshrc`).

  By the way,you should know that `sudo` command change current user,default `root`.So if you have to change user to `root`,maybe you should put it in `/root/.bashrc`
- Or you can make a link

  ```
  ln -s /usr/local/bin/pip2.7 /usr/local/bin/pip
  ```

Also you can try to use `virtualenv`,it's the best choice for multiple versions in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

A very intuitive and straightforward method is just modify the settings in `/usr/local/bin/pip`. You don't need alias and symbolic links. For mine:

## 1. Check the infor:

```
lerner@lerner:~/$ pip -V
```

> `pip 1.5.4 from /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (python 3.4)`

```
lerner@lerner:~/$ pip2 -V
```

> `pip 9.0.1 from /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (python 2.7)`

```
lerner@lerner:~/$ whereis pip
```

> ```
> pip: /usr/local/bin/pip3.4 /usr/local/bin/pip2.7 /usr/local/bin/pip
> ```

## 2. Change the setting:

Change the python3 to python2, be careful of its version(1.5.4 to 9.0.1 everywhere). And I just change the pip file to this:

```
lerner@lerner:~/$ sudo vim /usr/local/bin/pip
```

> ```
> #!/usr/bin/python2
> # EASY-INSTALL-ENTRY-SCRIPT: 'pip==9.0.1','console_scripts','pip'
> __requires__ = 'pip==9.0.1' import sys from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
>
> if __name__ == '__main__':
>     sys.exit(
>         load_entry_point('pip==9.0.1', 'console_scripts', 'pip')()
>     )
> ```

## 3. Now save and check:

```
lerner@lerner:~/$ pip -V
```

> `pip 9.0.1 from /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (python 2.7)`

Done.