# Changing the default pip

Tags: python, installation, pip, development-environment

I have two locations of pip.

```
which -a pip
```

returns

```
/opt/moose/miniconda/bin/pip
/Users/sterlingbutters/anaconda3/bin/pip
```

I would like to use the pip located in anaconda by default so that packages install in the anaconda environment. The configuration must leave the default python as that installed under the miniconda environment. In addition, the pip under the miniconda environment is associated with Python2 and the pip under the anaconda environment is associated with Python3. How can I change the default pip so that running

```
pip install <package>
```

installs to the anaconda environment?

Also, what is the difference between regular pip, pip2, and pip3? If I am using python 3, do I need pip3 (I have regular pip)?

All help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: `pip` is default name for pip installed for your default python. `pip2` is for python2, `pip3` for python3.

Comment: so in a sense, if you have pip, you have pip2 and pip3?

Comment: is this my answer: "You can set the following environment variable:

PIP_TARGET=/path/to/pip/dir" ? -> Can confirm this did not work

Comment: In layman terms, the pip is for the first python version you install. Next time you install a separate version, the new one becomes pip2 or pip3 correspondingly.

Comment: ahhh I see, thank you, so it really doesn't matter what pip you run

Comment: Please see my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51055425/3552975