# pip installing to python 3.6 folder instead of python 2.7 folder

Tags: python, package

Ubuntu 18.04 used by me (a noob) who has pip installed packages all over the place until I learned the benefit of virtual environments. My .bash rc file contains:

```
  #setup for python
    export PYTHONPATH=/home/stefan/.local/
    export PYTHONPATH=/usr/local${PYTHONPATH:+:${PYTHONPATH}}
    export PYTHONPATH=/home/stefan/caffe/python:$PYTHONPATH
    LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib${LD_LIBRARY_PATH:+:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}}
```

Anyway because I kept forgetting which virtual environments had which packages, I decided to use pip install --user like so:

```
pip install plumbum --user
```

which gave

```
~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages$ ls
plumbum  plumbum-1.6.7.dist-info
```

meanwhile

```
~/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages$ ls
clonevirtualenv.py       stevedore
clonevirtualenv.pyc      stevedore-1.30.1.dist-info
imageio                  virtualenv-16.4.3.dist-info
imageio-2.5.0.dist-info  virtualenv_clone-0.5.1.dist-info
pbr                      virtualenv.py
pbr-5.1.3.dist-info      virtualenv.pyc
pip                      virtualenv_support
pip-19.0.3.dist-info     virtualenvwrapper
six-1.12.0.dist-info     virtualenvwrapper-4.8.4.dist-info
six.py                   virtualenvwrapper-4.8.4-nspkg.pth
six.pyc
```

Needless to say, I cannot use plumbum from a python2 prompt. I only use pip install so I 
To make matters more confusing I have a virtual env named pyCV3 which has

```
~/Envs/pyCV3/lib/python2.7/site-packages$ ls
backports
backports.functools_lru_cache-1.5.dist-info
backports.shutil_get_terminal_size-1.0.0.dist-info
cloudpickle
cloudpickle-0.8.1.dist-info
concurrent
cv2.so
cycler-0.10.0.dist-info
cycler.py
cycler.pyc
dask
dask-1.1.4.dist-info
dateutil
decorator-4.4.0.dist-info
decorator.py
decorator.pyc
easy_install.py
easy_install.pyc
enum
enum34-1.1.6.dist-info
futures-3.2.0.dist-info
imageio
imageio-2.5.0.dist-info
IPython
ipython-5.8.0.dist-info
ipython_genutils
ipython_genutils-0.2.0.dist-info
kiwisolver-1.0.1.dist-info
kiwisolver.so
matplotlib
matplotlib-2.2.4.dist-info
matplotlib-2.2.4-py2.7-nspkg.pth
mpl_toolkits
networkx
networkx-2.2.dist-info
numpy
numpy-1.16.2.dist-info
pathlib2
pathlib2-2.3.3.dist-info
pexpect
pexpect-4.6.0.dist-info
pickleshare-0.7.5.dist-info
pickleshare.py
pickleshare.pyc
PIL
Pillow-5.4.1.dist-info
pip
pip-19.0.3.dist-info
pkg_resources
pkg_resources-0.0.0.dist-info
_posixsubprocess32.so
prompt_toolkit
prompt_toolkit-1.0.15.dist-info
ptyprocess
ptyprocess-0.6.0.dist-info
pygments
Pygments-2.3.1.dist-info
pylab.py
pylab.pyc
pyparsing-2.3.1.dist-info
pyparsing.py
pyparsing.pyc
python_dateutil-2.8.0.dist-info
pytz
pytz-2018.9.dist-info
PyWavelets-1.0.2.dist-info
pywt
scandir-1.10.0.dist-info
scandir.py
scandir.pyc
_scandir.so
scikit_image-0.14.2.dist-info
scikit_learn-0.20.3.dist-info
scipy
scipy-1.2.1.dist-info
setuptools
setuptools-40.8.0.dist-info
shutil_backports
simplegeneric-0.8.1.dist-info
simplegeneric.py
simplegeneric.pyc
six-1.12.0.dist-info
six.py
six.pyc
skimage
sklearn
subprocess32-3.5.3.dist-info
subprocess32.py
subprocess32.pyc
tlz
toolz
toolz-0.9.0.dist-info
traitlets
traitlets-4.3.2.dist-info
wcwidth
wcwidth-0.1.7.dist-info
wheel
wheel-0.33.1.dist-info
```

Early on I also did a 'sudo pip install' so my system python folders look like this

```
~/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages$ ls
clonevirtualenv.py       stevedore
clonevirtualenv.pyc      stevedore-1.30.1.dist-info
imageio                  virtualenv-16.4.3.dist-info
imageio-2.5.0.dist-info  virtualenv_clone-0.5.1.dist-info
pbr                      virtualenv.py
pbr-5.1.3.dist-info      virtualenv.pyc
pip                      virtualenv_support
pip-19.0.3.dist-info     virtualenvwrapper
six-1.12.0.dist-info     virtualenvwrapper-4.8.4.dist-info
six.py                   virtualenvwrapper-4.8.4-nspkg.pth
six.pyc
```

and

```
/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages$ ls
plumbum  plumbum-1.6.7.dist-info
```

So I dont know why pip install decided to put plumbum into 3.6 instead of 2.7. Can someone enlighten me? (And perhaps give me a hint on how to clean up my mess).

I suspect it has something to do with the fact that my linux always uses pip3

```
~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages$ pip3 --version
pip 19.0.3 from /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pip (python 3.6)

~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages$ pip --version
pip 19.0.3 from /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pip (python 3.6)


~/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages$ pip --version
pip 19.0.3 from /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pip (python 3.6)

~/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages$ pip3 --version
pip 19.0.3 from /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pip (python 3.6)
```

I know there is a pip2 in my /usr/bin but linux does not like it

```
/usr/bin$ pip2 --version
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pip2", line 9, in <module>
    from pip import main
ImportError: cannot import name main
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general you can call your Python interpreter with `./your/path/python -m pip install plumbum --user`, to use the right pip.

Comment: pip --version
pip 19.0.3 from /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pip (python 3.6)
stefan@4930:~/Envs/pyCV3/bin$ pip2 install plumbum --user
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pip2", line 9, in <module>
    from pip import main
ImportError: cannot import name main

Comment: python2.7 -m pip install plumbum --user

Comment: put plumbum into ~/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages

Comment: Try `~/Envs/pyCV3/bin/python -m pip install plumbum --user`

Comment: well, my machine thinks 'python' refers to python2.7

Comment: ~/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages$ python pip --version
pip 19.0.3 from /home/stefan/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip (python 2.7)
~/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages$ pip --version
pip 19.0.3 from /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pip (python 3.6)

Comment: as you can see from that poorly formatted comment above 'python pip' returns the python2 library but plain old 'pip' sends things to the python3 library

Comment: I marked querenker's answer but I wish I could split the vote since you all have been kind and helpful

Comment: I also have pip3 installed. How do I tell my machine that 'pip' refers to pip2 and how can I fix pip2 because as you saw, 'pip2' gives an error.

Comment: In order to change your default pip there is an helpful question here on SO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42871090/change-default-ubuntu-pip-to-pip2-7

Comment: pip2 -V
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pip2", line 9, in <module>
    from pip import main
ImportError: cannot import name main

Comment: how could i fix it?

Comment: Have you tried to call pip from your python interpreter with the `-m pip' option?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191045/discussion-between-aquagremlin-and-querenker).

Answer (score 2):

The reason why pip installed to your python3.6 library is because it is a default library for pip installation on your machine.

`pip --version` will return the location where pip is going to install your packages.
If you want to install the package for python2.7, run `pip2 install plumbum --user`

I would also recommend to run `pip2 --version` beforehand.

EDIT:

I suggest you also look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40832702/10520989) answer, to make sure you understand the differences between `pip`, `pip3`, `python`, `python2`, `python3`

Answer (score 1):

Try to write on terminal 'python2.7 -m pip install ' if it fails  install pip with a [get-pip.py](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/) file, and try again, if it does not work, let me know