# How to set default python3 to python 3.9 instead of python 3.8 in Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Tags: python, python-3.x, ubuntu

I have installed Python 3.9 in the Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. Now the system has both Python 3.8 and Python 3.9.

```
# which python
# which python3
/usr/bin/python3
# which python3.8
/usr/bin/python3.8
# which python3.9
/usr/bin/python3.9
# ls -alith /usr/bin/python3
12583916 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 9 Jul 19  2021 /usr/bin/python3 -> python3.8
```

But the `pip3` command will still install everything into the Python 3.8 directory.

```
# pip3 install --upgrade --find-links file:///path/to/directory <...>
```

I want to change that default pip3 behavior by updating the symbolic link /usr/bin/python3 to /usr/bin/python3.9.

How to do that?

```
# update-alternatives --set python3 /usr/bin/python3.9
This command will not work as expected.
```

**Here is the pip3 info:**

```
# which pip3
/usr/bin/pip3
# ls -alith /usr/bin/pip3
12589712 -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 367 Jul 13  2021 /usr/bin/pip3
# pip3 -V
pip 20.0.2 from /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip (python 3.8)
#
```

The `alias` command will not work:

```
# alias python3=python3.9
# ls -alith /usr/bin/python3
12583916 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 9 Jul 19  2021 /usr/bin/python3 -> python3.8
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42871090/change-default-ubuntu-pip-to-pip2-7/51275052 but use the correct pip instead of 2.7

Comment: Thank you. I have added the pip3 info in the post. But I still don't know how to do that, can you help?

Comment: An easier option is to run pip "correctly" via the python command itself:
`python -m pip install ...`

Comment: The "python3.9 -m pip install ..." will have problem when I added the pip3 option "--find-links file:///path/to/directory", it won't recognize the /path/to/directory at all. But if I use the above "pip3 install .. -find-links file:///path/to/directory", then the pyhton 3.8 can recognize it correctly. So I need to change the default python 3.8 version to python 3.9. and then use the pip3 as usually.'

Comment: Gotcha. The problem is that you also need to change the pip executable symlink as I understand you've done for the python executable.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You should be able to use `python3.9 -m pip install <package>` to run pip with a specific python version, in this case 3.9.

The full docs on this are here: https://packaging.python.org/guides/installing-using-pip-and-virtual-environments/

If you want python3 to point to python3.9 you could use the quick and dirty.

```
alias python3=python3.9
```

EDIT:

Tried to recreate your problem,

```
# which python3
/usr/bin/python3
# python3 --version
Python 3.8.10
# which python3.8
/usr/bin/python3.8
# which python3.9
/usr/bin/python3.9
```

Then update the alternatives, and set new priority:

```
# sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python3 python3 /usr/bin/python3.9 1
# sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python3 python3 /usr/bin/python3.9 2
# sudo update-alternatives --config python3
There are 2 choices for the alternative python3 (providing /usr/bin/python3).

  Selection    Path                Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
  0            /usr/bin/python3.9   2         auto mode
  1            /usr/bin/python3.8   2         manual mode
* 2            /usr/bin/python3.9   2         manual mode

Press <enter> to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number: 0
```

Check new version:

```
# ls -alith /usr/bin/python3
3338 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 25 Feb  8 14:33 /usr/bin/python3 -> /etc/alternatives/python3
# python3 -V
Python 3.9.5
# ls -alith /usr/bin/pip3
48482 -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 367 Jul 13  2021 /usr/bin/pip3
# pip3 -V
pip 20.0.2 from /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip (python 3.9)
```

Hope this helps (tried it in wsl2 Ubuntu 20.04 LTS)

Comment: This command will not work "alias python3=python3.9", after executing the command, the "ls" still shows the python 3.8. I have added the alias command output in the post. Please help to check.

Comment: alias python3=python3.9 works for me on centos7

Answer (score 12):

Changing Python version:

First we need to check what are the versions in Python using this command: `sudo ls /usr/bin/python*`

And then need to use this command to symlink them:

```
sudo ln -sf /usr/bin/python3.9 /usr/bin/python3
```

When you use that command, it will use `python3.9` as the default `python3`.

Comment: I got `Operation not permitted` on my mac.

Comment: for me on centos 7, after compiling  python3.9 is installed in /usr/local/bin e.g. `sudo ln -sf /usr/local/bin/python3.9 /usr/bin/python3`